# Disconnecting socket after certain amount of time that no data recceived

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm just making my server disconnect sockets that send no data after a certain amount of time, like 20 seconds.

I wonder whether working with timers is good for that or is there something special for that in socket library? Working with timers on the server for every socket makes it heavy.

Is it unsafe to make the client program handle that? For example every client disconnects after not sending data for a while.

Comment: What about one timer that checks all active clients periodically. You need to update last receive time per client, when data is received, and ensure proper synchronization.

Comment: @AlexFarber maybe. ttl does work for this? how can i use it for this?

Comment: @AlexFarber please send me you sample code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be very easy to implement as part of your keep-alive checking. Unless you're completely ignoring the issue of dropped connections, you probably have a keep-alive system that periodically sends a message client->server and vice versa if there's been no communication. It should be trivial to add a simple "last data received time" value to the socket state, and then close the socket if it gets too far from `DateTime.Now`.

But the more important question is "Why?". The best solution depends on what your reasons for this are in the first place. Do you want to make the server usable to more clients by dumping those that aren't sending data? You'll probably make everything worse, since the timeouts for TCP sockets are more like 2-4 minutes, so when you disconnect the client after 20s and it reconnects, it will now be using two server-side ports, instead of one. Oops.

As for your comment on the deleted answer, `and connection without data send and receive i think it gonna waste your threads` points closer to your real problem - the amount of connection your server has should have no relation to how many threads the server uses to service those connections. So the only thing an open connection would "waste" is basically a bit of memory (depending on the amount of memory you need per connection, plus the socket cost with its buffers) and a TCP port. This can be an issue in some applications, but if you ever get to that level of "load", you can probably congratulate yourself already. You will much more likely run out of other resources before getting anywhere close to the port limits (assumption based on the fact that it sounds like you're making an MMO game). If you do really run into issues with those, you probably want to drop TCP anyway and rewrite everything in UDP (or preferrably, some ready solution on top of UDP).

Comment: Thanks Luaan. Would you be more detailed in `a keep-alive system that periodically sends a message client->server and vice versa if there's been no communication`... Do you mean broadcasting to a bunch of alive clients  at specific intervals? If that's what you mean, can we consider it as a good workaround for ~20K online users?

Comment: @revo Yeah, sure. Of course, having 20k online users on a single server already needs some network configuration (most importantly, increasing the number of ephemeral ports on the server), so it might be a good idea to go through your requirements and figure out whether TCP is a good idea after all. A nice networking library on top of UDP (for example Lindgren) might be more in line with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Client-Server model describes how a client should connect to a server and perform requests. 
What I would recommend to you would be to connect to the server, and when you finish retrieving all the date you need, close the socket (on the client side).

The server will eventually find the socket's resources released, but you can check for the socket's [Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to release the resources sooner.

Comment: It's an online game so there is no definition of "all data". Connection is constantly alive until user logs out manually.

Answer (score 0):

When client disconnect to server then server can get disconnect event. it look like

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
 // Disconnect event handling 

});
```

On client side you also findout disconnect event .. in which you need to reconnect the server.